# Friendly Slugs for Special/Foreign Characters

Tags: meteor, iron-router, friendly-url, slug

The friendly slugs package for Meteor seems like it only supports English characters. (https://atmospherejs.com/todda00/friendly-slugs)

Does anyone know a good approach to creating slugs for foreign (or special) characters in Chinese, Japanese, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a package that answers my issue here:
https://atmospherejs.com/ongoworks/transliteration
https://www.npmjs.com/package/transliteration

This package(s) - though still early on development - translates foreign characters in Chinese, Japanese, and Korean into their English-letter counterparts or as close to it as possible and also allows the option to slugify them ready for URL purposes.

What a great package!